# What is the idiomatic way to clone a MutableMap?

Tags: kotlin

I have a MutableMap called `translations`.  I want to clone this, into another MutableMap or a Map.  I have done this with the following:  `translations.map { it.key to it.value }.toMap()`

This doesn't 'feel' right to me.  Is there a more idiomatic way to clone a MutableMap?

Comment: Not answering the question for Kotlin 1.0.5, but in 1.1 it will likely be `translations.toMutableMap()`, as it is now in 1.1 EAP.

Answer (score 3):

In Kotlin 1.1+ you can use [`toMutableMap`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-mutable-map.html):

```kotlin
val mutableMap = mutableMapOf("a" to 1, "b" to 2)
val mutableMapCopy = mutableMap.toMutableMap()
mutableMap.clear()
println(mutableMap) //=> {}
println(mutableMapCopy) //=> {a=1, b=2}
```

Kotlin Playground: https://pl.kotl.in/LGhPpdjv5

---

The Kotlin 1.0.x Standard Library does not define an idiomatic way to copy a map. A *more* idiomatic way would be `map.toList().toMap()` but sometimes the *most* idiomatic way to do something in Kotlin is to simply define your own [extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html). e.g.:

```
fun <K, V> Map<K, V>.toMap(): Map<K, V> = when (size) {
    0 -> emptyMap()
    1 -> with(entries.iterator().next()) { Collections.singletonMap(key, value) }
    else -> toMutableMap()
}

fun <K, V> Map<K, V>.toMutableMap(): MutableMap<K, V> = LinkedHashMap(this)
```

The above extension functions are very similar to what is defined in [release 1.1-M03 (EAP-3)](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/tag/v1.1-M03).

From [kotlin/Maps.kt at v1.1-M03 · JetBrains/kotlin](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/v1.1-M03/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/Maps.kt#L442-L460):

> ```
> /**
>  * Returns a new read-only map containing all key-value pairs from the original map.
>  *
>  * The returned map preserves the entry iteration order of the original map.
>  */
> @SinceKotlin("1.1")
> public fun <K, V> Map<out K, V>.toMap(): Map<K, V> = when (size) {
>     0 -> emptyMap()
>     1 -> toSingletonMap()
>     else -> toMutableMap()
> }
>
> /**
>  * Returns a new mutable map containing all key-value pairs from the original map.
>  *
>  * The returned map preserves the entry iteration order of the original map.
>  */
> @SinceKotlin("1.1")
> public fun <K, V> Map<out K, V>.toMutableMap(): MutableMap<K, V> = LinkedHashMap(this)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The intended way for that is `translations.toMutableMap()`. Unfortunately it does not preserve the nature of the map, meaning that the resulting class will depend on the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```kotlin
yourMap.toMap().toMutableMap()
```

Here is extension function:

```kotlin
MutableMap<K, V>.copy() = this.toMap().toMutableMap()
```